# Why Photon gas's Equation of State Diverges?

Tags: thermodynamics, energy, statistical-mechanics, photons, bosons

We know that, for *Photon gas*, the equation of state is given by $pV=\frac{1}{3}U$; where $p$ is the Pressure, $V$ is the Volume and $U$ is the Internal Energy of the Photon Gas. ([see Equation of State of Photon gas](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MNPkh.jpg) (as done with Grand Canonical Partition Function & Grand Canonical Potential Function))

For *Nonrelativistic Bosons* (e.g. Higgs Boson), the *Equation of State* can be shown as $pV=\frac{2}{3}U$; where $p$ is the Pressure, $V$ is the Volume and $U$ is the Internal Energy of the Nonrelativistic Boson Gas (by considering $\varepsilon=P^2/2m$; where $\varepsilon$ is Kinetic Energy, $P$ is Linear Momentum & $m$ is Mass of Nonrelativistic Boson). ([see Equation of State of Nonrelativistic Fermion & Boson gas](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0SJG8.jpg) (as done with Average Number of Nonrelativistic Bosons in Energy state $\varepsilon\ {\rm and}\ \varepsilon+d\varepsilon$))

But, we know that **Photon is Ideal Relativistic Boson**. So, if we apply the [Relativistic Approach](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BEWLQ.jpg) i.e. $\varepsilon=Pc$; where $c$ is Speed of Light, on the Average Number of Photons (Relativistic Bosons), we should get the Equation of State $pV=\frac{1}{3}U$ for Relativistic Bosons. But, the problem there is, it will be true if and only if it could be shown that
$$I=\int_0^\infty \frac{d \varepsilon}{e^{\varepsilon/k T}-1}=0,$$
but actually it is $\infty$ as shown in the [Calculation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Isod0.jpg).

Then, how can we show that, for Photon gas $pV=\frac{1}{3}U$ in this way?

Comment: The bosonic results is for massive bosons with dispersion relation $E=\frac{p^2}{2m}$, whereas photons are massless bosons with $E=pc$.

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't quite follow your calculations for $U$, especially when the bracket appears line $3$. Normally you do a simple integration by parts to get the state equation. You have for non-interacting bosons, with density of state $D$ :
$$
\Omega = -T\int d\epsilon D(\epsilon)(-\ln(1-e^{-\beta(\epsilon-\mu)}))
$$
$$
U = \int d\epsilon D(\epsilon)\frac{\epsilon}{e^{\beta(\epsilon-\mu)}-1}
$$
So it is tempting to relate the two by an integration by parts. This is possible when in general: $D(\epsilon)\propto 1_{\mathbb R_+}(\epsilon)\epsilon^\alpha$ (for 3D photons, $\alpha=2$ and $\mu=0$). Both integrals are well-defined as long as $\alpha>-1$ (for low energy limit, high energy is exponentially supressed). You therefore get:
$$
U = \left[-TD(\epsilon)\epsilon(-\ln(1-e^{-\beta(\epsilon-\mu)})\right]_0^\infty-(\alpha+1)\Omega
$$
and the bracket is trivial since $\alpha>-1$, so the power law overcomes the $\ln$ in the low energy limit, and you still have exponential suppression in the high energy limit. If you further assume $D(\epsilon)\propto V$, then
$$
\Omega=-pV
$$
and you recover:
$$
U = \frac{1}{1+\alpha}pV
$$
and as a sanity check, you can see that the condition $\alpha>-1$ is important for the final result to make sense.

Hope this helps and tell me if you need more details.

Comment: Can you please tell me what is $\alpha$ here? And in the 3rd line in my calculation, I made the Nominator of the integrand as a differential of the Denominator.

Comment: $\alpha$ is a general exponent for your density of state described by a power law. For example, in $n-$D, for massless particles, $\alpha=n-1$ (so in 3D $\alpha=2$ as you had shown), while for massive particles, $\alpha=n/2-1$ (so in 3D $\alpha=1/2$ as you must have seen).

Comment: I finally understood your notation. I think you should review integration by parts, not only your notation is misleading, but your method is problematic. You can't isolate $I$ away, you forgot to include the power factor. This is the key ingredient to make the bracket vanish. In general try to avoid giving the same name to different variables especially if one is free and the other isn't.

Comment: I didn't isolate $I$, I calculated the inner integral $I$ separately, so that the main calculation of $U$ doesn't become clumsy. Can you please elaborate about the Power Factor? I am unaware of it.

Comment: Yes, you calculated the antiderivative separately, which was a good idea, but for the bracket limit you forgot to take into account the extra $\epsilon^3$ factor, so while it is true that $I\to \infty$, $\epsilon^3I\to 0$.

Comment: Oh, I see. I only thought about $I$, but didn't considered the $\varepsilon^3I$. Togather they tends to 0 as $\varepsilon \rightarrow 0$. Thank you